# Strategies to run code every few hundreds microseconds?

Tags: multithreading, timer, operating-system, scheduling

Let's assume that we have a reasonably modern computer, running on one of the major operating systems; If we need to run a code that will access a location in the main memory to read, another location in the main memory to write; No other calculations whatsoever; The thread running this code will need to do it periodically every 900 microseconds, with +/- 100 to 150 microseconds as a range of accepted latency; Then what are the available strategies to achieve that with very high level of reliability?

The question framed differently would be, how can I not get trapped by the scheduling behavior of the OS, without severely limiting available processors for other tasks to run?

Comment: This is the type of problem that a real-time operating system solves.  A conventional multiuser operating system can't guarantee it.

Comment: @NateEldredge Can a conventional multiuser OS tho let me make a thread running without leaving the processor virtually at all, so that the thread periodically does the task?

Comment: You mean you want to dedicate one core exclusively to that thread?  Again, generally no; the OS can always pre-empt the thread to do other stuff.  Some OSes have partial realtime features, like the scheduling parameters on Linux, but AFAIK their guarantees are pretty weak.

Comment: @NateEldredge It is the level of guarantee that lead me to ask the question, and add a hundred microsecond of delay as a margin of error. 
If common OSes behavior of scheduling on modern cpu, using say sleep_for() 800microsecond, will end up most of the times with less than 100-200 microseconds of delay, then it is for me a guarantee to do the job.